# In ASP.NET MVC, what is the advantage of using @RenderSection (versus say @RenderPage)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to be enlightened if I'm doing something wrong. I bet I am.

If I have the following code in my view page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}

<h2>About</h2>
<p>
    sample content.
</p>
@section header
{
    <div id="header">
        Chapter 3a: Creating a Consistent Look
    </div>
}
```

...I should also have the ff in my layout page to render the section (if available) to prevent an exception at run-time:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("header"))
{ 
    @RenderSection("header")
}
```

However, if I don't have the last 4 lines above that checks for the section before rendering the section (say, I commented them all), the compiler will not check that I have a section defined in my view page, and allow me to build and run the application. During run-time, it is only then that I will get this error when I run the page:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml": "header".

My questions then are the ff:

1. How can we prevent this from happening? Is there any setting that forces the compiler to check for the missing `@RenderSection` code?
2. Doesn't the usage of the `@section` feature make a system less maintainable (assuming question #1 has no positive answer) since we need to manually search for the presence of the `@section` keyword throughout the entire application?
3. In this case, what is the advantage of using `@RenderSection` then as opposed to `@RenderPage`?
4. Can we also make the `@section` conditional?

Answer (score 2):

I've never thought of this as an issue. The concept is the same of placeholders in aspx syntax, so if you have 2 placeholders in your homepage, you're supposed to have 2 contents in each page/view using that masterpage.

There's a blog post of Phil Haack on the argument, it doesn't address your concerns directly but it's surely something interesting to consider.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. as for section's relationship with the concept of placeholder, from what I understand, the presence and/or absence of a placeholder object is checked in server-side code (since you can not use a placeholder object in code behind if that placeholder object does not exist in your page), while the string (say, "header") is not checked at compile time. I hope I'm understanding your usage of placeholder correctly. thanks!

Comment: Actually, not. That's not how it works. Code behind isn't related at all. Actually, since Mvc2 aspx views don't even have a code behind file. What I meant is that, at concept level, the <asp:ContentPlaceHolder /> tag is equivalent to the @RenderSection() statement, and the <asp:Content> tag is equivalent to the @section{} declaration. I was not implying that they work exactly the same. Still I'm sure none of the two are checked at compile time. You can try to set the <mvcBuildViews> tag to true in the csproj and see if anything improves.

Comment: i understand what you mean. i thought you were referring to this placeholder (<asp:PlaceHolder>) than to this placeholder (<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>).

As for their similarity (ContentPlaceHolder == @RenderSection(); Content == @section), you seem to be correct as far as I understand. However, what makes the ContentPlaceHolder/Content pair different from the @RenderSection()/@section pair is that the ContentPlaceHolder/Content pair (and their relationship to each other) is more evident/explicit/visible than the @RenderSection()/@section pair.

Comment: Aside from the fact that the IDE provides the tooling to connect the two when you want to use the ContentPlaceHolder (in the MasterPage) in your ASPX page.

Answer (score 2):

i know its old but if someone passed by this.

@RenderSection("header", required: false) by this you can either have a
@section header { } in your view page or not.

And now you can also remove the check condition from your layout.
also by this its conditional!

if you want it to be required you can :
@RenderSection("header", required: true) but by this if your view doesn't have a @section header it will throw an error.